Checking for empty dictionary item (not key)
Every now and then an empty item is added to a dictionary when I don't check it the key exists.  I know why it's happening, but I don't know how to check if it has.  For instance, in the code segment below;
dictVar("Happy") = 23
dictVar("Lucky") = 666
if (dictVar("Oopsie") = 23) then
   {Do Something}
end if

I mistakenly check for "Oopsie" entry.  The dictionary.keys watch list will show the 3 keys, the dictionary.items list shows 23 and 66 respectively for "Happy" and "Lucky".  "Oopsie" shows "Empty" as the value (no quotes) as the key didn't exist when I referenced it.  No big surprise.

I'd like to code an routine to handle this kind of issue, but I can't find anything on how to check the item of a dictionary key for "Empty".  I have tried "is empty" and "is nothing" - both fail as the item value appears to be inaccessible.
Everything I find online refers to an empty Key, and that it adds if not checking EXISTS first, not nothing on checking the item value itself.
Is there a way to check for this?

First check if the key exists, and then check if the value associated with the key is Empty

I am not sure if this is what you want, but give it a try...
If you want to check if it is empty or not, use the alternative IF statement.
Sub Test()
    Dim dictVar As Object, Key As Variant
    Dim myCheck As Boolean
    
    myCheck = False
    
    Set dictVar = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    dictVar("Happy") = 23
    dictVar("Oopsie") = 9978
    dictVar("Lucky") = 666
    
    For Each Key In dictVar.keys
        If Key = "Oopsie" And dictVar(Key) = 99 Then
'        If Key = "Oopsie" And dictVar(Key) <> "" Then
           myCheck = True
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox IIf(myCheck, "OK", "Not OK")
End Sub



Well, that's just weird :(  I swear I tried before and the IF statement crashed.  it worked this time so yeah!
I do check using .EXISTS when coding.  I was just curious as how to check as the crashes are usually because of a coding/logic error (when the code expected the determined key to be there, but I'd coded the wrong variable or key condition), which have to be corrected anyway.   It would be nice if you could check specifically for "Empty" as I could see some possibilities where a blank could be a valid item value.
Thank you, again.

Did you try  If Key = "Oopsie" And dictVar(Key) <> "" Then

As I said, "Oopsie" was just an example.  When I do have a crash it's because of an unexpected (as in I don't know what the key being used is), so I was (am) building a generic error trap.  The <>"" works for most cases, as long as a blank Item cannot be a valid entry.  In my case, that's true. For some that might not be the case.  It's surprising there isn't a build-it empty check as Nothing and Empty are valid comparisons for other variable types, just not Dictionaries. An Empty item is a common instance simply because of how Dict vars are handled.  But answer ckecked above is good for me.

If the key "Oopsie" does not exist in the dictionary, the following code will create a new key named "Oopsie" with an empty value.
if (dictVar("Oopsie") = 23) then

Before proceeding with the if statement, use the Exists function to verify the presence of the key in the dictionary object.
dictVar("Happy") = 23
dictVar("Lucky") = 666
Const SKEY = "Oopsie"
If dictVar.Exists(SKEY) Then
    If dictVar(SKEY) = 2 then
       {Do Something}
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "the key " & SKEY & " is not exits"
End If

